# How to read text in table from word document with java

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

i´m trying to read all the texts (text in a table too) in a word document **.docx** with java. With this code i can only read the text outside of the table:

```
try{
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Path_to_Word_Document)
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis))
List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphList = document.getParagraphs();
     for(XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphList){
       if(paragraph.getText().contains("X-01234-64572")){
        System.out.println(paragraph.getText().contains("X-01234-64572")
       } else {
        System.out.println(System.out.println(paragraph.getText().contains("X-01234-64572")
      }
   }
}
```

Can you please tell me: how to get the text **X-01234-64572**?[image]

Comment: Thank for your comment. I tried with your solution, but i can not get the text "X-01234-64572". Can you please write the corect code for my case?

Comment: i hope it works:  https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?resid=CD114530660D905E!944&ithint=file%2cdocx&wdOrigin=OFFICECOM-WEB.MAIN.MRU

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it will return the content of the table cells

```
 XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(FILE_PATH));
    for(XWPFTable table : doc.getTables()) {
        for(XWPFTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
            for(XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                System.out.println("cell content: " + cell.getText());
            }
        }
    }
```